# Extract drawingManager polygon path Google Maps on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have a Google map with drawing manager enabled where a user can draw a polygon and save it to my db. I added an event listener to the drawingManager object for the overlaycomplete event. When the event is fired, the coordinates of the polygon are written to a hidden field. This works great - the only problem being that if the individual vertices are dragged/changed after that point the event isn't fired. I need to either update the field on(any)change or iterate through the polygon vertices when the user hits submit and write them to the hidden field. I can't quite figure out how to get this to work, but you can see what I have so far here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4WT/21/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:450px;"></div>
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="map_form">
  <input type="text" name="vertices" value="" id="vertices"  />
  <input type="button" name="save" value="Save!" id="save"  />
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var map; // Global declaration of the map
var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // Global declaration of the infowindow
var lat_longs = new Array();
var markers = new Array();
var drawingManager;
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.9403762, -74.1318096);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
                },
                        polygonOptions: {
                            editable: true
                        }
            });
            drawingManager.setMap(map);

            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function(event) {
                var newShape = event.overlay;
                newShape.type = event.type;
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
                $('#vertices').val(event.overlay.getPath().getArray());
            });
        }
 initialize();

$(function(){
    $('#save').click(function(){
        //iterate polygon vertices?
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html) which uses the DrawingManager and exports polygon paths.  Based off the [Blitz Map Editor](http://code.google.com/p/blitz-gmap-editor/) project.

Comment: @geocodezip thank you! I was able to extract the bit I needed and it works great!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Figured it out!!**

I added function overlayClickListener:

```
function overlayClickListener(overlay) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, "mouseup", function(event){
        $('#vertices').val(overlay.getPath().getArray());
    });
}
```

and attached it to the overlay on overlaycomplete:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function(event){
                overlayClickListener(event.overlay);
                $('#vertices').val(event.overlay.getPath().getArray());
            });
```

For the solution in action, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/rvsMH/1/

Comment: How to load the polygon in drawing again using the coordinates?

Comment: @JeevaJsb, did you find out how to do that?

Comment: what is your need? if you tell me, I will try to answer.