# Export drawmanager polygon by DOM button

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to modify code it this question [Extract drawingManager polygon path Google Maps on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454919/extract-drawingmanager-polygon-path-google-maps-on-click). I want to fire the coordination update by DOM button.
Below is original code, it's works very well:

```
function exportCoor(overlay){
             google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, "mouseup", function(event) {
                    $('#textarea').val(overlay.getPath().getArray());
                });

function initialize(){  
  //some code 
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {
                    exportCoor (event.overlay);  
    }
}
```

I want somethink like this:

```
function exportCoor(overlay){
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(exportBtn, "click", function(event) {
              $('#textarea').val(overlay.getPath().getArray());
                });

function initialize(){  
    //some code 
    ...
```

or

```
function exportCoor(overlay){
                    $("#exportBtn").click(function(event) {
                        $('#textarea').val(overlay.getPath().getArray());
                    });
```

first neither second doesn't work. Please, can someone advise any solution?

Thx, Jakub

Comment: Probably a little more complicated than you need: http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html

Comment: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ps4g/) that outputs the vertices to a div in the DOM when the "Save" button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the vertices (and you need a reference to the polygon(s):

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    vertices = "";
    for (var i=0; i<polygons.length; i++) {
        vertices += "polygon "+i+"<br>";
        for (var j=0; j<polygons[i].getPath().getLength(); j++) {
            vertices += polygons[i].getPath().getAt(j).toUrlValue(6)+"<br>";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('verticesclick').innerHTML = vertices;

});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ps4g/)