# For Each Loop for Google Map DrawingManager Polygons?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I've set up an Ionic 4 Application using Angular 8 with a google maps component.  In the component, I will need to draw multiple polygons, be able to edit them, and eventually save their vertices in a database.

If I could hard code some number of polygons this is a pretty trivial task through the polygon.getPath() or polygon.getPaths() method.

However, I'm using the google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager component, and the only way I've seen people extract points is through using event listeners like in question [15454919](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454919/extract-drawingmanager-polygon-path-google-maps-on-click).  I've implemented something similar here:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', (polygon) =>  {
  console.log(polygon.getPath());
});
```

The post recommends an improvement by nesting a mouseup listener in this function, which may or may not work, but I'm thinking there should be a better way to solve this problem.

Is there some "for each" loop type of functionality which can extract data from every polygon created with the drawingManager tool?  The idea is to hit a submit button and grab every instance of a polygon at the page at once.

**HTML**

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Map
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <div #map id="map"></div>
    <ion-button (click)="submit()"> Submit</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

**Typescript**

```
export class HomePage {

@ViewChild('map', { static: false }) mapElement: ElementRef;
map: any;

constructor() {}

ionViewDidEnter() {
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(someLat, someLng);
    let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false
};

this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: ['polygon']
    },
    polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        draggable: true,
        editable: true
    }
});

drawingManager.setMap(this.map);

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', (polygon) =>  {
     console.log(polygon.getPath());
});

}

submit() {
    //Compile all polygons then
    //Post to database here
}

}
```

Again, I could use the listener method by simply appending to an array, but I would have to add handling for polygons edited after they were created, and it seems like it would be pretty bad programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is what you want so i will share some codes in the comment and see if this is what you want else it would be just a help approach.

Comment: this.watch = Geolocation.watchPosition({}, (position, err) => {

    if (position) {

      this.addNewLocation(

        position.coords.latitude,

        position.coords.longitude,

        position.timestamp

      );

    }

  });

Comment: this.markers.map(marker => marker.setMap(null));

  this.markers = [];

 

  for (let loc of locations) {

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng);

 

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({

      map: this.map,

      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

      position: latLng

    });

    this.markers.push(marker);

  }

Comment: The first for storing data and the second is for extracting data into map.Regards.